# Regex extracting price or number value from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to extract the value `-1,234.23` from the following string using JavaScript regex?

> "hello-sdvf-1,234.23 23 everybody 4"

should extract

> -1,234.23

This regex returns `null`:

```
"hello-sdvf-1,234.23 23 everybody 4".match(/-?\d+\.\d+/);
```

and that one is OK for

```
"hello-sdvf-134.23 23 everybody 4".match(/-?\d+\.\d+/);
```

I need to extract numbers with commas, too.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: What are the requirements? Will there be multiple values in one string? Should the number be negative?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex:

```
-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?
```

It matches an optional hyphen (`-?`), then 1 or more digits (`\d+`), then optional 3-digit groups (`(?:,\d{3})*`), then an optional decimal part (`(?:\.\d+)?`).

```js
var s = "hello-sdvf-1,234.23 23 everybody 4";
var res = s.match(/-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/);
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Or, to match multiple values:

```js
var re = /-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/g; 
var str = 'hello-sdvf-1,234.23 23 everybody 4';
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML += m[0] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="r2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `regex`:

```js
var str = "hello-sdvf-1,234.23 23 everybody 4";

str.match(/[+\-]?\d+(,\d+)?(\.\d+)?/)[0];


alert(str.match(/[+\-]?\d+(,\d+)?(\.\d+)?/)[0]);
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `-?`: Matches zero or one `-` literal
2. `0-9`: Matches any number
3. `,`: Matches `,`
4. `.`: Matches `.` literal
5. `+`: Matches previous group one or more time

Comment: Your regex will also match [`......`](https://regex101.com/r/uA6gJ3/1).

Comment: Ok, there is another problem here, but I will leave it for you to spot :)

Comment: @stribizhev Fixed missed `\-`. Anything else to fix?

Comment: I do not want us to have identical answers :)

Comment: @stribizhev: Talking about duplicate, hope you have seen my answer posted 2 min before your answer :)

Comment: @anubhava: I wrote my answer long before yours (check timestamp on my comment under the OP question), but was waiting for OP to provide some efforts. Since you all made a "spoiler alert", I posted mine, too.

Comment: Key is if you see an answer already posted same as yours, avoid posting dups.

Comment: @anubhava: You have a different regex, anyway. The `\b` is redundant. And this soultion is flawed anyway.

Comment: I also posted answer after OP showed his attempt. I guess you also realize that just a difference of `\b` doesn't make it a different regex for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
var re = /\b[+-]?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\b/;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB0fK9/2)

**Code:**

```
var m = "hello-sdvf-1,234.23 23 everybody 4".match(re);
//=> ["-1,234.23"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I've come up with an initial function which does something slightly different. It will extract the numerical value from a string and convert it to a number type.

Because numbers are formatted differently in various locales, you can define which characters are expected to be used as thousands separators (default=","), and which are used for the decimal point (default=".").

```
    function extractNumber(value, thousands, decimals) {
        thousands = thousands || ',';
        decimals = decimals || '.';
        var regexp = new RegExp("[+-]?\\d+(?:["+thousands+"]\\d{3})*(?:["+decimals+"]\\d+)?", "g");
        value = value.match(regexp)[0];
        value = value.replace(new RegExp('['+thousands+']', 'g'), '');
        value = parseFloat(value);
        return value;
    };
```

Usage example:

```
extractNumber("hello-sdvf-1,234.23 23 everybody 4");
```

Returns

```
-1234.23 (a number, not a string)
```